# Is it possible to leverage OS X Touch ID or Watch 2 Factor authentication in a webpage or app?

Tags: macos, apple-watch, touch-id, multi-factor-authentication

I've seen samples of 2 factor authentication with [Windows Hello](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/04/12/a-world-without-passwords-windows-hello-in-microsoft-edge/#WGWVRV7Ggw1C6rxG.97) on Microsoft Edge, and want to see if a comparable authentication is possible with either

- [Touch ID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207054) (integrated in OS X on newer MacBook Pros)
- Log in with [Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206995) (available on MacBook Pros > mid 2013)

Answer (score 0):

There are no available APIs for logging in with the Apple Watch how Apple does with the macbook. There are APIs available for touchID to be used in iOS apps, not on a web page.

[Local Authentication Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication)